# How to implement a left to right navigation menu?

Tags: angularjs, menu, navigation, ionic-framework

"Left to right navigation menu"?
It's hard to describe what I mean. I'm new to Ionic but I need a special navigation bar below my action bar. I want to click on an item in my action bar and a navigation menu should be opened. The navigation menu should have many levels. But if I choose one item in the list, I want to see the last list and the new one. And I can slide through the menu (left & right). 
Hope you know what I mean. How can I implement this? Is there any name for it?

**UPDATE:**

It's a bit similar to this:
http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/complex-navigation-patterns-for-responsive-design/#ol-left-to-right

With the difference that the old menu should not disappear, but stay on the left side of the menu.

Comment: Not sure but may be you're looking for this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not I am searching for...

Comment: Checkout Ionic "Modals"